# Apply a test by groups

Tags: r, autocorrelation

I have a data sample on five-minute asset price returns (`FiveMinRet`) and select events for a period covering several years. These events are hypothesized to have an effect on the `FiveMinRet` (/causing non-zero abnormal returns). From the time series data sample, I construct a sub-sample containing for all events only the, say, 100 minutes (windows) around each event, (`sub_sample`).
As a part of a preliminary data analysis, I wish to formally test for the presence of heteroskedasticity and first-order autocorrelation within each window. Each window occurs on different dates, so a variable (`Date`) will be my grouping variable.

So my question in this regard is: Is there a way to apply a Ljung-Box test (`Box.test(x, lag = 1, type = c("Box-Pierce", "Ljung-Box"), fitdf = 0)` command in R) by groups (`Date` variable) and to present the test statistics/test results in a list or data frame?

I tried the following approach

```
Testresults = df %>% group_by(Date) %>% do(tidy(Box.test(df$FiveMinRet_sq, lag = 1, type = c("Ljung-Box"), fitdf = 0)))
```

The output is what I am looking for, however, by this approach, I obtain the same test statistics for all dates, so my approach is incorrect.

Comment: You should add example data and make this generally reproducible, please read: [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible example in the question I can't test the code for this solution, but one way to separate the tests by `Date` is to use `split()` and `purrr::map()`.

```
df %>% 
     split(.$Date) %>% 
     purrr::map(.,function(x){
          do(tidy(Box.test(x$FiveMinRet_sq, lag = 1, type = c("Ljung-Box"), fitdf = 0)))     
     }) -> testResults

# combine into a data frame
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,testResults))
```